# Is there any way to improve poor antenna reception between an old computer to a modern digital TV?

Tags: tv, hdtv, antenna

I just got an Atari 65XE, and the machine itself works fine. One issue I’m having trouble with with my collection of older computers is that digital TVs do not seem to get the frequencies input just right.

In the case of the Atari 65XE, there’s quite a bit of static noise in the image, in the case of my older computers (like the ZX80) it seems the TV just “loses” the frequency for short periods of time. This does not happen in CRTs. I’m connecting all these machine through these old antenna switches like the one below. I don’t want to mod the machines themselves.

Is there a way to clean the image in these newer TVs?

[image]

Comment: The fault may not be with the modern TV, but with the older RF modulator. Have you tried tweaking its transmit frequency a bit to see if it clears things up?

Answer (score 2):

The Atari 65XE has a 5-pin DIN composite video port which should have composite video on pin 4 and ground on pin 2. If you’ve got some spare parts you can make your own cable with DIN on one end and an RCA jack on the other end, and plug it into your TV’s composite input.

[image: Atari 65XE (Rear View)]

Here are the pinouts according to [this Atari 8-bit FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/atari-8-bit/faq/section-17.html). I made one of those cables myself, many years ago.

```
Monitor port (female jack): (all but 400, NTSC 600XL, SECAM 800XL,
3 o     o 1                  SECAM 130XE, XEgs)
   o   o
 5   o   4
     2
1. Composite Luminance (except PAL 600XL: Not Connected)
2. Ground
3. Audio Output
4. Composite Video
5. Composite Chrominance (except 1200XL: Not Connected; PAL 600XL: Ground;
                          all but very late-production 800XL: Not Connected)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the old days you could tweak the TV tuning to be “just right” even if it was slightly misaligned with the defined frequencies allocated to the TV channels. This did not matter with old TVs because tuning was analog.

With modern TVs the tuning is digital and they won’t necessarily cater for of a few tens or hundreds of Hz misalignment. You just don’t have that control anymore. In the old days, after the modulator warmed up a bit it drifted off-tune and a small tweak to the old-fashioned TV tuner re-aligned it; you don’t have that facility in modern PLL (phase-locked loop) digital tuners.